# Connect Multiple Buttons: Rewind & Play/pause button for one action

Tags: iphone

I have multiple UIButtons in my app. Want to connect Rewind & play/pause Button for one action. Not using interface builder at all for app.

Right now rewind button has this method when it is pressed

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
[timer invalidate];    
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
MainViewController *viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[viewController release];
[audioPlayer play];
 self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
 target:self
 selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
 userInfo:nil
 repeats:NO];
}
```

and play/pause button has this method when it is pressed

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];
}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
  if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }
   } 
   }
```

When the rewind button is pressed, it should do the play/pause action method, means, when rewind button is pressed then play/pause button should toggle to pause button and when pause button is resumed, then it should toggle to play button.

Answer (score 1):

An action method/selector can be connected to a UIButton using code:

```
 [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(method:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

You can add same actions to UIButton using above line of code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you want to call the same method when Play/Pause or Rewind button is clicked.

Just add this in addition to your existing code after connecting this method as the target for both your buttons.:

set a unique tag for your Play and Rewind buttons

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton *)[sender];
    if (clickedButton.tag = playButtonTag){
        [self playPauseAction:sender];
    }
    else{
        [self rewindAction:sender];
    }
}
```

For sake of simplicity I have used if else. you could use if/if, or switch-case in place if this. Hope this helps!

Comment: whenever rewind button is clicked i want to execute rewind action method and at the same time want to execute playpauseAction method as well.

Comment: true. set your rewindButtonTag = 888 and playButtonTag = 999 , it should work. (if its not working, let me know whats happening.)

Comment: i don't know much about the tag concept and what is the purpose to tag rewind and play button. can it be done without tagging both button.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW25 since UIButton is derived from UIView, you can refer to this documentation. I am not sure why you want to do it without tagging the button. There certainly will be many different ways to solve a problem, but I guess no ones going to list out every possible solution to this problem!

Comment: when you create your button, it'll be like UIButton *theButton = [UIButton alloc] init]. after that just like you assign color to it like theButton.backgroundColor = [uicolor clear color], you do the same with tagging it like theButton.tag = 888

Comment: i did tagged the button. -(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    UIButton *clickedbutton = (UIButton *)[sender];
    if (clickedbutton.tag = playButton.tag){
        [self playpauseAction:sender];
    }
    else{
        [self rewind:sender];
    }
}
getting two warnings in red for these two statements  UIButton *clickedbutton = (UIButton *)[sender];
    if (clickedbutton.tag = playButton.tag){ expected identifier and use of undeclared identifier playButton